# FullCalendar 3 in french language

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

How i can change the default language and format of FullCalendar who use the Moment.js to manage time.

Examples if possible please

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                lang: "es",
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',` , try tihs one

Comment: in v3 it is now **locale** instead of **lang** - you can find a demo @ https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.0.0/demos/locales.html - if you only include a single locale (fr.js for example) you do not have to set the **locale** per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this ?

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            lang: 'es'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Source : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/lang/

Comment: lang: 'fr' for French